# SSIS string truncation error appears to be invalid

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb

I have an OLE DB Destination that has all string fields as Varchar(MAX).
When I run my package, I get the infamous Truncation error on my summary column (My data source has Summary Column):

> Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column " Summary" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page."

My package fails, but when I set the Summary column to "Ignore Failure", my package works.

I wasn't expecting that to be the solution to my problem, because my destination field is a column called Synopsis which is varchar(max).  I shouldn't have gotten the error in the first place!

What's going on?  Any ideas?  I have searched other solutions, but couldn't find this scenario.

Here is screenshot:
[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: The error is happening on the Flat File Source, not the Database Destination; it's your source that is configured incorrectly. The error is showing you exactly where the problem is. My guess is you have defined all the columns with the default length of 50.

Comment: It defaults to 50 on the inbound.  I get it.  Didn't know about this setting.  New to ssis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source has some column mapping with incorrect length.

Comment: this answer is correct, so I am not sure who is giving negative marks, although Lamu's comment above is a better explanation....